# Segmentation fault while installing any linux distro (or windows)

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

I'm need of a little help from you.

I'm having troubles while installing any distribution of Linux (or even Windows) in a computer .. I never had troubles installing an operating system in this computer (I assembled this computer while I was in college.. circa year 2004)

- Motherboard: PC Chips m863g v. 7
- Processor: AMD Sempron 2400+ (1.6 Ghz)
- RAM: 1 GB
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce FX 5500 (256 MB RAM)

Originally, to make my motherboard to detect my Processor as an AMD Sempron 2400+ I had to set the CPU frequency at 166 Mhz. It worked OK this way for several years.

Some months before, I started to have some troubles with the computer, as I had Windows on it. Since then, I have tried to install Gentoo, Debian, Ubuntu and some other Linux distros with no success.

When I try to install any Linux distribution, I get an Segmentation fault error just after the boot screen / splash screen of the installation media. .

I tried to run MemTest images and it completes successfully every time (so I discarded the RAM module as the source of the problem)

The funny thing is that, if I reduce the CPU frequency to 133 Mhz, the errors don't appear anymore, and let me install the operating system (despite the resulting installation is quite slow).

So my questions are:

- Why would the PC throw segmentation faults on CPU Frequency @ 166 Mhz but working fine at @ 133 Mhz?
- Is there any software tool useful for diagnose this kind of errors in hardware?

Comment: What happens if you don't change your CPU's clock speed at all? Why do you need to change the frequency?

Answer (score 0):

When BIOS autodetects your CPU the frequencies and scales/multipliers are always set proper, as default. When you overclocks it your run it at own risk. Generally, it can work , but it can be critical as well. Data corruption may happen at some certain modes of CPU when it changes  internal clock modes.

Remember, the certain model of CPU has been tested at certain clocks/speed. The only reason that a manufacturer did not label it a with higher rate and did not sell it at more expensive price - is the CPU gave errors at one (or more) test(s) of all test set at clocks higher than it, in fact, has been sold.